# Mixed content and IFrame

Tags: c#, security, iis, https

we have an old web site that is implemented with an outer site called LaunchPad that calls other sites on the same domain but different subdomains, like this:

Note that the iframed content has no http:// urls specified.  I searched the whole site for them.

Still, i get a mixed content error similar to the one on this link:  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170476-Troubleshooting-mixed-content-errors

When i browse the the page with the iframe in it, it just hangs and never renders and i get the mixed content.  We are using the latest Chrome Browser.

The weird thing is if i go on the physical machine where the web server is located and browse on that machine, there is no error.  It only breaks when i am browsing from another machine.
I had my co worker browse and same result.

Any idea why it works from the browser on the server only?  We are using IIS 8.5
Bindings are set for http AND https for subdomain, and a cert of format *.domain.com is installed for the https binding.

Comment: Post needs more details on what exactly happens. "iframed content has no http:// urls specified" is the only piece of information about the page in the post. Maybe add output of "network" tab in the browser (as text, possibly with domain names replaced)…

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a  tag in the web config, which toggles http to https and vice versa.  Removed that and finally problem went away